# TypeError: Cannot access member 'code' of undefined

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-design, contract-debugging

I am new to geth command line for testnet in Windows. I got an error when trying to deploy this contract example

```
----------------------------------------------
source = "contract test { function multiply(uint a) returns(uint d) { return a * 7;} } ";

contract = eth.compile.solidity(source).test;

txhash = eth.sendTransaction({from: primary, data: contract.code});

eth.getBlock("pending", true).transactions;

miner.start(1); admin.sleepBlocks(1); miner.stop();

contractaddress = eth.getTransactionReceipt(txhash).contractAddress;

eth.getCode(contractaddress);

multiply7 = eth.contract(contract.info.abiDefinition).at(contractaddress);
fortytwo = multiply7.multiply.call(6);
```

---

I read similar questions, but did not help! most of the answers telling ignoring 'undefined' during compiling the code (the second command). But when i tried the third command i got this error

> TypeError: Cannot access member 'code' of undefined  at
>   :1:52

Is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: That code doesn't compile for me - it missing a `function` keyword, and there's an extra `;` at the end. Can you confirm that this is the exact code you're trying to compile?

Comment: Thanks Richard, sorry for the typing mistake. it does have 'function' + ;. i updated the question